# Pasting charts in order shown in Excel Workbook into PowerPoint Slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to copy and paste charts from a worksheet into a slide in PowerPoint.

These charts are now lined up in two rows and three columns:

```
Chart 1   Chart 2   Chart 3 
Chart 4   Chart 5   Chart 6
```

I want to paste these charts in the same order in PowerPoint.

When I use my command `ws.ChartObjects.Count`, it counts the charts vertically, as in:

```
Chart 1   Chart 3   Chart 5
Chart 2   Chart 4   Chart 6
```

So now this is also the order in which they are pasted in PowerPoint.